# Codeigniter - getting array from form validation config file

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to get array from form validation config file in controller?

> application/config/form_validation.php

I have an idea to save my form validation array into config.php, and than to reference it in form_validation.php. Then I will be able to get it in controller, and be able to use it in validation.

Is there any better (direct) way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$this->config->load("form_validation");
```

Then

```
$this->config->item($key_name);
```

Docs:- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/config.html

Comment: I am new to CodeIgniter world, so I was confused with `$config[]` variable. I thought that `$config[]` from config.php will overwrite `$config[]` from form_validation.php file when I do `$this->config->load("form_validation");
`. I am wrong, right? :)

Comment: The documentation has explain this :- `Note: If you do create your own config files use the same format as the primary one, storing your items in an array called $config. CodeIgniter will intelligently manage these files so there will be no conflict even though the array has the same name (assuming an array index is not named the same as another).`

Comment: its not working, this only return config item, not array from config>form_validation.php